# New user cannot login

Tags: user

I created a new user. Added all the groups that the "pi" user belonged to.
When I try to login with that user, it just keeps recycling back to the login.

If I login with the user "pi", I can su to the user with the same password.

What am I missing?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: What was the exact set of commands you've used?

Comment: It's also worth noting that when you use `su` with administrator rights (like the default pi user has) you don't need to use their password.

Comment: What does the user's entry in `/etc/passwd` look like?

Comment: Its very confusing, but `adduser` and `useradd` are very different. `adduser` creates the home directory and sets up password and defaults, `useradd` just adds the entry in `/etc/passwd`

Answer (score 2):

First, delete the user created.

Next, I type `$ groups pi` to check the group's user pi belong. Then I create a new user with the command

`$ useradd -m -G [groups from user pi except for pi and sudo] username`.

The `-m` option creates a home directory and `-G [groups]` option adds the user to those groups. 
Set up a password to the new user with

`$ sudo passwd username`.

After that, log out and log in to the new user account.
You can find more specific steps on this [website](https://www.dummies.com/computers/raspberry-pi/managing-user-accounts-raspberry-pi/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

1. check if the home folder has been created (it was missing)
2. check the passwd file `sudo nano /etc/passwd` (the bash was missing)

there should be a line like this:

```
paolo:x:1001:1001::/home/paolo:/bin/bash
```

(my user is paolo)

Else try deleting and recreating the user, it worked for me!!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`su` on its own defaults to the root user. If you use `su - username`, then it will try to login to that user.

Comment: Thanks but that is what I did and it works. what does not work is login at boot!

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct password?

Comment: yes that's why i tested it with su

Comment: Do you remember the exact useradd command you used?

Comment: yes. adduser newuser

Comment: Did you set the login shell? If not, you need to do `usermod -s /bin/bash newuser` (or whatever shell you want)

Comment: that reports back "no change" what is the shell is the gui